# fixed div box at bottom left corner

Tags: css-position

I want my green div box in fixed position at the bottom left corner of the page. But it is overlapping on the left navigation. I want green div box start its fixed position after the left navigation items end. Following is the code I have uploaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/remqf/

It is working fine in big screen resolution but in small resolution, green box is overlapping on the left navigation.  Is there any possibility to restrict the green box after navigation end with 50 pixel gap and when we scroll down the page it is also fixed at bottom left corner in every resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give the impression of a gap above the green box by adding a top 50px border? http://jsfiddle.net/Y3qWu/